# Linux directory name contains \t

Tags: linux

I want to get the file path of the directory which has the name contains tab(\t) due to that i am unable to find the fully qualified path. ex: `cd /data/    emplates` is not working

Thanks in advance

Comment: `cd '/data/    emplates'` ?

Comment: Try `cd /data/?emplates`.

Comment: Not working @JoachimSauer

Comment: Does tab-completion also not work? Both of these work for me. How do you know that the "empty space" is exactly `\t`? Have you tried `cd /data/*emplates`?

Comment: the exact problem is in the java code the  folder path has backward slash instead of forward slash which is \data\navigate\template so the directory created with the name has new line and tabs.

Answer (score 0):

Quoting the parameter to `cd` is necessary:

```
cd '/data/  emplates'
```

You probably can't copy and paste this into terminal, but you can enter the literal tab character into terminal by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>, followed by <kbd>Tab</kbd>.

Alternatively, this should work:

```
cd /data/''$'\t''emplates'
```

Comment: Thanks for  the reply , the exact problem is in the java code the  folder path has backward slash instead of forward slash which is \data\navigate\template so the directory created with the name has new line and tabs.